# Ceiling / round / floor in prolog

Tags: prolog

When I try to execute the following query with prolog swi  version 7.2.3,

`ceiling(1.5)` it says,

```
 ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: ceiling/1 (DWIM could not correct goal.)
```

How do I get the "ceiling" working for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use it in an expression, I suppose, in this way

```
X is ceiling(1.5), write(X)
```

Comment: Why do you need to `write(X)`?

Comment: @Boris - not really a need; just to show how to use (and show) the value